# Setting TopIndex to programmatically generated ActiveX ComboBox

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I am trying to set the first value of the list of several ActiveX ComboBoxe in MS Excel using the `TopIndex` property.
This should be easilly done using the following :

```
ComboBox1.TopIndex = *whatever*
```

The problem is that my ComboBoxes are dynamically generated using a loop, so I can only access them using an `OLEObjects` object.

I tried the following:

```
i = 0
Do Until IsEmpty(Sheets("temp").Range("A1").Offset(0, i).Value)
        'First I create a Range to populate each ComboBox
        Set rngdata = Sheets("temp").Range(Sheets("temp").Range("A1").Offset(1, i), Sheets("temp").Range("A1").Offset(1, i).End(xlDown))
        'Now I create the ComboBoxs
        Set rng = Sheets("temp").Range("A1").Offset(0, i)
        With Sheets("temp").OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=rng.Left, Top:=rng.Top, Width:=rng.Width, Height:=rng.Height)
            .Name = "patapouf" & i 'name
            .Object.List = rngdata.Value 'Populate the list from rngdata
            .Object.AddItem "All" 'I add a new value "All"
            .Object.TopIndex = .Object.ListCount 'I put the choice "All" in first position
        End With
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

Excels returns:
"Error '380' :
Unable to define TopIndex property. Property value invalid.
(Translated from original error in French : Erreur d'exécution 380 : Impossible de définir la propriété TopIndex. Valeur de propriété non valide).

The error comes from this line:

```
.Object.TopIndex = .Object.ListCount
```

I believe that using ".Object.TopIndex" isn't the way to process with ActiveX ComboBox, but I can't find any other way to formulate it.

Comment: It sounds to me like you want the `Listindex` property (which starts from 0, not 1)?

Comment: Isn't ListIndex just the position of the selected item in the ComboBox's list? How can I change the list order to put "All" first using it?

Comment: `.Object.TopIndex = .Object.ListCount - 1`

Comment: Same error as before. In facts even giving it a fixed value returns the same error 380. For example `.Object.TopIndex = 5 ` doesn't work (I have more than 5 values so no problem with 5)

Comment: You can't move the item to the top of the list using either `Topindex` or `Listindex`. You should specify the position as the second argument to `AddItem`

Comment: It worked, I thought `Topindex` and `Listindex`were values meant to be changed, the same way you can change the `TabIndex`value in a UserForm. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Rory pointed out, the position should be specified as the second argument to `AddItem`, and not by trying to change the value of `TopIndex`.

This solved the problem.